# HTML Right to left based on language of data

Tags: html, css, localization, internationalization, right-to-left

I have a use case where a paragraph of text could be in any language, based on data that was input by the user elsewhere. I need to display it in right-to-left or left-to-right based on the language of the value.

Note: I am not referring to the language of the whole page. I need to set the direction for this particular paragraph based on the data's language.

Is there any way to do that without using JavaScript?

Comment: Note: I need to do this on the client side (browser).

Comment: Also I would like to know whats the common practice to deal with use cases like this. Do you let the text inherit the direction based on the overall language/direction of the page? Or do you use JS and detect language for each element on the page and set direction at each element level (which I don't imagine many people would do, for performance reasons).

Comment: Do you know the data's language? If you do, then you also know the direction it will have. When you are generating the page, add a class accordingly and apply the `direction` attribute as they suggest on the answers below

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I do not know the data's language, hence the whole question :)

Comment: So you want to detect the data's language; and then, depending on it, select the direction of the text. That looks like it will need something more than just html5, css3, and JS

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro thanks, I ended up going with a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Natarajan: that's great. You should post it as an answer. That is something that could interest other people

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that ?

```css
#rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
#ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<p id="rtl">Foo</p>
<p id="ltr">Bar</p>
```

Comment: That always sets the direction specified. My question is whether there is a way to set the direction based on the language of the value. (If the value is in Arabic or Hebrew for instance, then the paragraph should be RTL. If it the value happens to be in English, then it should be LTR).

Comment: @NatarajanShanker I don't think you can do this without javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `direction`:

```
.sometext {
    direction: [ltr|rtl|inherit];
}
```

Comment: That always sets the direction specified. My question is whether there is a way to set the direction based on the language of the value. (If the value is in Arabic or Hebrew for instance, then the paragraph should be RTL. If it the value happens to be in English, then it should be LTR).